# Generate URL and keep GET parameters Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I searching for the Symfony way of handling keeping the current `GET` parameters.

lets say the current url is: `http://example.com/cars/?q=Volvo%p=1`

Now i have to generate a url based on the current one but modify a parameter: `http://example.com/cars/?q=Volvo%p=2`

Im searching for the symfony best practice solution for such a case, it can't be the right way simply generating the url by appending all known get parameters by hand.

Doing something like:

```
$this->generateUrl( 'some_route', array( 'q' => $request->get('q'), 'p' => $request->get('p') ) );
```

or

```
$this->generateUrl( 'some_route', array_merge( $request->query->all(), array( 'p' => $request->get('p') + 1  ) ) );
```

just feels wrong.

There has to be a nice and clean solution for this. Im thinking of something like this:

```
<!-- path( <route>, <params>, <persist current> ) -->
{{ path( 'some_route', { p: 2 }, true ) }}
```

The `fuelPHP` framework for example has the [update_query_string](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/uri.html#/method_update_query_string) method for this.

Comment: Do you want to do a pagination? Does this GET parameters come from a form?

Comment: Yes but not all `get` parameters are from the pagination. Thats why i have to persist all of them.

Comment: Where does the get parameters come from? From the page, a form, session?

Comment: Forms, links, handwritten basically they could be from everywhere. Just every parameter inside `$request->query->all()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did:

```
{{ url('my_route', {myparam:'value'}|merge(app.request.query.all)) }}
```

Comment: That looks like a part of a twig file. Would you add that to every link in all your twig files?

Comment: Yes, this is part of my twig file and you'd need to add that to every twig file where you need that functionality. Alternatively you could write your own twig function for URLs generation as described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$this->generateUrl('some_route', $request->query->all())
```

Comment: And merging the new parameters everytime? Isn't there a method that brings that simple functionality?

Comment: @Mario my example is identical to `array( 'q' => $request->get('q'), 'p' => $request->get('p') )`, but easier..

Comment: I know. what i'm asking, is this the right / best solution? I hate repeating code, well that solution would force me to or writing a helper. But I think, i'm simply missing something, because I can't be the first one crossing this problem.